# Communication protocol of camears via usb port

Tags: camera, usb, signals

I'd like to know how to communicate with cameras over their usb port. 
It should be possible to read the live-view images, set shutter and trigger the cam.
There is a lot of software out there, and I'd like to write my own app to control a old nikon d90.

Any references or sources where I can go on asking?

Comment: Do you have a particular language in mind to accomplish this?

Comment: I prefer high-level languages but ansi c would work too. I found the picture transfer protocol (ptp) to be cabable of what I need. Though I'm not sure how to implement it. I'd like to connect a mobile device by usb to the cameare.